# docker-compose in gitlab-ci: expose ports

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

I like to set up a gitlab repository and a gitlab-ci with docker-compose for integration tests.

I finally managed to start some containers with docker-compose.

```
image: docker/compose:1.29.2

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  DOCKER_HOSTNAME: myhost
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "" #TODO

services:
  - name: docker:dind
    alias: docker
    command: [
      "--registry-mirror=https://artifactory.mycorp.net"
    ]
```

Now I am faced with the problem, that I need network interaction with some services that run on a windows server with (for the tests irrelevant) UI and stuff - so I can not dockerize them with adequate effort.

The gitlab-runner runs exclusively on the server for this one project only!

My idea is, I need to get the docker:dind-service to be on the *host*-network, so the docker-containers that are spawned inside that service will be available through their explicitly exposed ports. However I have no clue on how I might achieve that.
Any other way to solve that problem is also welcome!

Comment: Have you tried adding `network_mode = "host"` to your `[runners.docker]` section of the runner [configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section)?

Comment: Yep, got that idea right after posting this question. However, with that it fails with: `create service container: Error response from daemon: conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior (docker.go:1155:0s)` - probably related to [this](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4548)

Comment: Hmm. In which case, this may be tricky to accomplish with the docker executor and dind service. Not ideal, but your best option may be to cut out the dind service by either (1) directly exposing the host daemon to the job or (2) using the shell executor for your jobs instead (and therefore using the host docker daemon directly).

Comment: Thanks you! I will try to figure it out, how to get it running with you proposed approaches.

Comment: @sytch: Shell-Executor is no solid solution: It easily fails with cleaning up, e.g. if for some reason (maybe misconfiguration or planned) a container creates files with the wrong uid. Do you have a hint where to start with your proposed (1)? Unfortunately I do not have full control over the configuration of each service.

Answer (score 1):

I figured a solution that seems to run for now:

1. Create a network, e.g `docker network create gitlab-runner` (bridge-mode)
2. [Configure the gitlab-runner to use that network](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#legacy-container-links) by setting the `network_mode` to afore created networks name (e.g. "gitlab-runner").
3. Start the *dind*-container manually, connected to afore created network, exposing the necessary port(ranges)
4. Don't create the *dind*-container as service in the .gitlab-ci.yml

So far it seems to work for a minimal example starting up zookeeper, kafka and a kafka-restproxy.
For the full project I still have some errors, but I assume they are unrelated to this issue. If it turns out to be wrong, I'll keep you updated.

> Actually the errors are related to this issue: With this method, the checked out project is available in the *docker/compose*-container. When starting the containers, this is done from the context of the *dind*-container, in which the files are not present.
> The files could be copied with a "build"-step in a new docker container first or made available through a shared volume.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta make sure that both services are within the same docker network to achieve what you want.  Generally when creating images they are assume different networks but this can be configured by u to allow them share the same network.
Below is an example of what I mean. Do the same for ur containers

`docker network create db_network docker run -d \ --name mysql-spi1 \  --publish 3306 \  --network db_network \ --restart unless-stopped \ --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ebsbduabdc \ --volume mysqlspi-datadir:/var/lib/mysql \ mysql:8 \  --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`