# Cannot connect to mysql Docker container in GitLab CI while it works locally

Tags: mysql, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

To load a MySQL-Dump into a database which is running in Docker, configured with the following docker-compose file

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  database:
    image: registry.var-lab.com/mysql/mysql:8.0.28
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: symfony
      MYSQL_USER: symfony
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfony
      MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony
    command:
      - '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
      - '--sql_mode='
      - '--max_allowed_packet=1073741824'
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "-u", "symfony", "-p", "symfony", "localhost" ]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'

   [... other services/containers ...]


volumes:
  database:
    driver: local
```

I am using the following command:

```
docker-compose exec -T database mysql -usymfony -psymfony symfony < ci/db_dump.sql
```

The command works on my local machine where I use exactly the same docker-compose configuration.

But when I run run the same command in the GitLab CI with the following configuration

```
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  CI_REGISTRY: git.xxx.de:5050

test_run:
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - apk add docker-compose git
    - git clone https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@git.xxx.de/xxx/testfiles.git testfiles
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker login -u reguser -p $VAR_LAB_REGISTRY_PASSWD registry.my-secred-domain.com
    # copy test files
    - mkdir -p files/import/fields && mkdir -p files/import/xxxx/data
    - cp testfiles/xxx/* files/import/fields
    - cp testfiles/xxx/* files/import/roadsurfer/data
    # done
    - docker-compose pull
    - docker-compose up -d
    - docker-compose logs
    - docker-compose exec -T database mysql -usymfony -psymfony symfony < ci/db_dump.sql
```

the command failes with this error message:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use docker-compose here? Since you're forced to use docker-in-docker then, you are only using the "same docker-compose configuration" in the literal config file sense. I think it would be easier for you to directly use your mysql image in the pipeline instead.

Comment: Yes I need it because it is a part of the envivonment where it is running in productive. Therefore, it makes sence to run the tests in the same environment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71512304/docker-compose-in-gitlab-ci-expose-ports has basically the same problem as you then.

Comment: That is not the same problem, because he is using a Windows environment, but my problem has nothing to with Windows.